# Showing $\nu_1^2 + \nu_1\nu_2 + \nu_2^2+\nu_2\nu_3 + \nu_3^2 > 0$ for $\nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3$ not all $0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $\nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ not all be zero.

I wish to show
$$\nu_1^2 + \nu_1\nu_2 + \nu_2^2+\nu_2\nu_3 + \nu_3^2 > 0\text{.}$$

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2Bx*y%2By%5E2%2By*z%2Bz%5E2+%3E+0) seems to suggest splitting this into cases, but I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to approach this. This expression seems very similar to the binomial expansion, minus the fact that we have three terms that are squared and two cross-terms occurring (rather than one cross-term multiplied by $2$).

As for my work, if any one of these are $0$, (I think) this is a trivial exercise. If any two of these are $0$, this is a trivial exercise (you're left with a squared non-zero term). But if all three are non-zero? Then I'm at a loss on how to pursue this, because there isn't a clean way to deal with three variables (or is there?). I've tried seeing if Wolfram could perhaps factor the above. It can't, but maybe, I thought, we could try working with
$$(\nu_1 + \nu_2 + \nu_3)^2 = (\nu_1^2 + \nu_1\nu_2 + \nu_2^2+\nu_2\nu_3 + \nu_3^2) +2\nu_1\nu_3+\nu_1\nu_2+\nu_2\nu_3$$
but there is no guarantee that this is $> 0$ either (take $\nu_3 = -(\nu_1 + \nu_2)$, for example).

Comment: Multiply the inequality by $2$ and complete the square.

Comment: That is a pain to type. Why not $a^2+ab+b^2+bc+c^2 > 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding Deathkamp Drone's suggestion,
though I thought of it independently:

We want to show that
$a^2+ab+b^2+bc+c^2 > 0
$.

This is the same as
$2a^2+2ab+2b^2+2bc+2c^2 > 0
$.

$\begin{array}\\
2a^2+2ab+2b^2+2bc+2c^2
&=a^2+a^2+2ab+b^2+b^2+2bc+c^2+c^2\\
&=a^2+(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+c^2\\
&\gt 0\\
\end{array}
$

unless
$a=0, a+b=0, b+c=0, c=0$
which implies that
$a=b=c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Complete the square. So start with $(v_1+\frac12v_2+\frac12v_3)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I could more or less instantly spot
$$\nu_1^2+\nu_1\nu_2+\nu_2^2+\nu_2\nu_3+\nu_3^3=(\nu_1+\frac12\nu_2)^2+\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\nu_2\right)^2+(\frac12\nu_2+\nu_3)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is positive definite. If you leave off the $1/2$ factor, you have the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of the form.

Meanwhile, if we allow $x,y,z$ to take only integer values, $$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + yz + xy $$ takes all integer values other than $4^k (16n + 14).$ Note that we need to allow $x,y,z$ to be positive, negative, or zero to guarantee getting all the promised (positive) integers.